# Graphics3D: Objects with holes

Tags: graphics3d

In a recent project, I found out that there is a big limitation when using `Graphics3D` to construct objects - it lacks the ability to construct objects with holes in them. For example, we can get a regular wall-like `Graphics3D` object with the `Cuboid` primitive, but we can not get a wall with a window. Like this one
 [image]

Naturally, a Boolean operation is the way to go. But, in *Mathematica*  the functions belonging to Boolean operations class, like `RegionUnion` and `RegionIntersection` can not be used in `Graphics3D`

Is there a way to construct `Graphics3D` objects with holes in them ?

Comment: related Q/A [How to make overlapped part to be transparent?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67549/125)

Comment: @kguler nice. To answer OP question, then one can just do `cub1 = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {20, 2, 20}];
cub2 = Cuboid[{12, 0, 8}, {17, 2, 17}];
r2 = RegionDifference[cub1, cub2];
RegionPlot3D[r2]` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0yVrz.png) but the edges need some work. Original question at http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/430092?p_p_auth=EAP2rQun

Comment: that post at wolfram is also mine. thanks for your suggestion very much!

Comment: I have [responded to the question on Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/430386).

Comment: Actually just wrap Show around mesh object. See the Community link I posted - there are mo answers there.

Answer (score 8):

*This is a [repost of Wolfram Community answer](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/430386)*

---

Let's start from your code:

```
cub1 = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {20, 2, 20}];
cub2 = Cuboid[{12, 0, 8}, {17, 2, 17}];
Graphics3D[{cub1, cub2}];
reg = DiscretizeRegion[RegionDifference[cub1, cub2]]
```

You have a lot of tetrahedrons:

```
MeshCells[reg, 3] // Length
```

> 10093

And a lot of polygons:

```
MeshCells[reg, 2] // Length
```

> 22096

You do not need all that for visual, - so get the surface (boundary):

```
surface = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg];
polygons = MeshCells[surface, 2];
polygons // Length
```

> 3820

Now so few polygons! Get the coordinates of the mesh too:

```
points = MeshCoordinates[surface];
points // Length
> 1910
```

And here you go:

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Gray], 
  GraphicsComplex[points, Polygon[polygons /. Polygon[x_] -> x]]}, 
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` instead of `DiscretizeRegion`?  (You get even fewer polygons.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 sure just was in a Rush ;)

Comment: This is not working in MM 12.1.1 I get an error "A non-degenerate region is expected at position..." Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way.

I'm going to use the `contourRegionPlot3D` function [from here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48530/862). I include the function definition here for convenience:

```
contourRegionPlot3D[region_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, {y_, y0_, y1_}, {z_, z0_, z1_}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{reg, preds},
  reg = LogicalExpand[region && x0 <= x <= x1 && y0 <= y <= y1 && z0 <= z <= z1];
  preds = Union@Cases[reg, _Greater | _GreaterEqual | _Less | _LessEqual, -1];
  Show @ Table[ContourPlot3D[
     Evaluate[Equal @@ p], {x, x0, x1}, {y, y0, y1}, {z, z0, z1}, 
     RegionFunction -> Function @@ {{x, y, z}, Refine[reg, p] && Refine[! reg, ! p]},
     opts], {p, preds}]]
```

Now create a region from the `Graphics3D` objects:

```
c1 = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {20, 2, 20}];
c2 = Cuboid[{12, 0, 8}, {17, 2, 17}];
c3 = Cylinder[{{5, -1, 10}, {5, 2, 10}}, 3];
reg = Fold[RegionDifference, c1, {c2, c3}];
```

Use `RegionMember` to turn this into inequalities:

```
ineqs = Rest @ RegionMember[reg, {x, y, z}]
```

> 0 <= x <= 20 && 0 <= y <= 2 &&  0 <= z <= 20 && ! (12 <= x <= 17 && 0
>   <= y <= 2 && 8 <= z <= 17) && ! (0 <= (1 + y)/3 <= 1 && (-5 + x)^2 + (-10 + z)^2 <= 9)

And then:

```
contourRegionPlot3D[ineqs, {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 20}, 
 Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]